# What is the level of strict-aliasing implied by the `restrict` keyword?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strict-aliasing

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int data[LENGTH];
}Data;
```

and use it like so:

```
Data* dt=CALLOC(...)

int foo(Data* restrict d){
    for(...)
        d[i]->data[j];
    //do stuff with data[]
}
```

My question is: Does removing strict aliasing from `d` also affect its members or do I need to use `restrict` on them separately? In other words, does `restrict` imply that *all* pointers contained in a struct get the same treatment?

Edit: By *level of aliasing* I mean, if a pointer to a struct gets `restrict`ed, would any other pointers contained in it be restricted as well (as is the case with my example).

Comment: `restrict` is not quite about strict aliasing.

Comment: It seems I have misunderstood then. What is `restrict`'s purpose?

Comment: `restrict` is essentially a promise by the programmer that a pointer is the only one through which accesses are made to the storage at which it points.

Comment: @gsg ...and essentially hints the compiler to remove aliasing checks from it? That's the idea I have

Comment: @rath Yes, but strict aliasing is something different. Strict aliasing is kind of implicit, and its applicability is assumed by performing type checking on pointers.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm a bit lost right now, if you understand the spirit of the question and can salvage it, please do so. Otherwise put it on hold and I'll edit when I've grasped the concept. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`restrict` only applies to the annotated pointer itself (or pointers generated from it, such as by pointer arithmetic), not any of the values retrieved through that pointer.

I'm not sure what 'levels of strict aliasing' is supposed to mean, but `restrict` is a more powerful promise than that of strict aliasing. Strict aliasing allows pointers of compatible type to alias: `restrict` is a promise that there is no aliasing at all.

Comment: The key essence of `restrict` is that a compiler is entitled to assume that if a function receives a `restrict`-qualified pointer and it can see everything that is done with that copy of the pointer or any other copies made therefrom, it can treat all accesses to things identified by that pointer as unsequenced relative to anything else in the system, *even in the presence of opaque function or accesses to pointers of unknown provenance*.